# A saying about Satan's ultimate power

Tags: idioms

I once came across an English saying that says Satan's ultimate power or trick is that he is hidden or cannot be seen (the saying might have the word *conceal*-not sure though). I could not find that saying.

What is that saying?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because The OP has answered their own question.

Comment: @KateBunting: It's perfectly fine to answer your own question.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find it after a few google searches later.

> The greatest trick the Devil ever pulled was convincing the world he
> didn’t exist—Charles Baudelaire

The second quote might come handy too.

> The second greatest trick the Devil ever pulled was convincing the
> world he is the good guy—Ken Ammi

Source: [Good reads](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/8784723-the-greatest-trick-the-devil-ever-pulled-was-convincing-the)